# Half Life War Boy Blood Transfusion

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

In Mad Max Fury Road, Nux bring his blood bag:

> Max

with him to keep him full of High Octane Crazy Blood. 
I'm wondering how the blood gets transferred. Is it simply a matter of the blood bag being higher than him and the blood following gravity.

Or does the bags side get hooked into an Artery to give it pressure and Nux's side into a vein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The needle is placed into an artery.  Sending hypoxic blood wouldn't do any good anyway.

The movie makes his quite unrealistic since it would spray blood all over the desert if it was ripped out like in the film.

Comment: That makes sense. It looked more like removing the kind of needle they take blood samples with from your arm that oozes a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Large-Gage needles, such as the ones used for donating blood or, evidently, what was suggested in the film, would indeed result in a rather significant mess if they were simply pulled out of the vein; the only reason they do not normally do so is because a gauze pad is immediately pressed onto the hole left behind. In my experience, this pad is pressed in place usually before the needle is even removed. Despite this precaution, I have seen small volumes of blood get squirted, usually no more than a few inches, while the needle is extracted and before the gauze is fully in place.  I would not want to see what would happen without the gauze pad.

Gravity, or more accurately, positive head pressure, would help to move blood from one vessel into another one that is suspended below it.  This trick is used in most normal whole blood donations, but is helped by the body's natural blood pressure.

On a theoretical side, a difference in blood pressures between Max and Nux could have aided the transferal, assuming that Max always had a higher BP.  Some might even theorize that having Max in front of an accelerating vehicle would in a small way help to drive blood back to Nux through inertia.  This should all be just chalked up to a little movie magic and impractical myth, however.

Comment: So to transfer the blood the needle would have gone into a vein not an artery?